# Сохранить данные запроса в базу данных

Tags: mysql, python, django, python-3.x

Всем привет, только знакомлюсь с django и возникла необходимость сохранить данные в БД с запроса, видел примеры сохранения формы но у меня нет необходимости использовать форму

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    phone_sim = request.POST.get('number')
    userAditional.telefon = phone_sim.get('number')
    userAditional.telefon.save()
```

Как всегда ответ очень простой, но по незнанию возникают трудности, с запроса переменная "number", в бд "telefon"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Входные данные, которые будут сохраняться в базу всегда нужно проверять. Поэтому лучше использовать форму. Модель не сохраняется, т.к. вы вызываете метод `save()` у атрибута модели.

```
userAditional.telefon = phone_sim.get('number')
userAditional.save()
```

Comment: Разве через форму не сложнее?

Comment: @maximus С формами легче валидировать данные. Так же если у вас будет несколько полей для сохранения, удобней будет создавать модель с помощью формы.

Comment: Я тут быстро накидал пример, все ли верно делаю?  
`class userAditional(models.Model):  
 telefon = models.IntField()`  
  
`class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):  
 class Meta:  
  model = userAditional  
  fields = [  
   "telefon",  
  ]`

Comment: @maximus это невозможно читать, в формах нет ничего трудного. Прочитайте в документации

Comment: ок, буду разбираться

Comment: может подскажите, если у меня в модели будут еще поля, но при сохранении формы заполню только одно поле в бд, не будет ошибки? На прямую при сохранении в модель выбивало ошибку "поле" not Null и еще, как записать просто переменную в модель при сохранении формы, чтобы полученные данные из формы и данные из переменной записались по одному и тому же id

Comment: @maximus Конечно будет ошибка валидации модели, если у поля нет параметра `default` с указанным значением или не стоит `blank=True` и `null=True` но это касается не всех полей, для `CharField` к примеру, лучше использовать только `blank=True`, погуглите про их различия это все есть в документации, даже в переводе